# Agora iOS Video not showing on web page

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm using Agora to do a video call between iPhone and a web page, but I can't seem to make it work on the web page side.

I'm using the native iOS SDK in version 3.2.1, so intercompatibility should be automatic for my COMMUNICATION profile. I first create and join the channel on iOS, and then join on the web side. On my iPhone, I have both my local video and the video from the webpage webcam. But on the web side, I can't seem to detect that the iPhone has already joined and display its stream.

To note : communication iPhone to iPhone works, and web to web also works.

I also use

```
agkit.setChannelProfile(.communication)
agkit.setClientRole(.broadcaster)
agkit.enableVideo()
        
agkit.muteLocalVideoStream(false)
```

to ensure that my iphone local video is streamed and sent to the web.

Is there something I'm missing to ensure that the web receives my local video stream ?

Answer (score 0):

You look to be doing everything right from the iOS side here.

Check on this site that the web is able to receive the video feed, if it doesn't show on this site then for some reason it isn't publishing.

https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/examples/LargeGroupVideoChat-Web/

Comment: Hello, @maxxfrazer, in my case its connecting with this webdemo page, but not actually with my own web and android app.All having same thing. Have you got any idea for that to be occur?